# Loop in ArrayList using viewPager in android

Tags: android, loops, arraylist, textview, android-viewpager

hope you fine and well,

i have the follwoing function which receive and arraylist called students:

```
 public void DisplyOnTextView(List< Student > students)
        {

                textView.setText(students.get(i).getDes());
                new LoadImage().execute(students.get(i).getUrl().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
        }
```

in my layout i have TextView and ImageView as shown in the previous code,
now i want to use a viewPager to loop through all students ! which mean when i slide the screen i want to show the information of the next student in the textview and the imageview, i tried many examples of viewPager but they are very complicated and they didn't solve my problem ! so any simple solution ?!

Comment: Hi, did you get it, Why are you ignoring the answer without giving any feedback,  If you didn't understand something there, you can freely ask, I am ready to help.

Answer (score 0):

To inform you This question is considered as **Too broad** because *good answers would be too long for this format*, Eventhough I am answering it to make you clear, because I had simple example that I tried before.

It's the first example I've done to practice the `ViewPager` and I made it simple as possible to make you understand this answer by removing many essential parts, Hope you will understand this, But I suggest you to see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) as well to greatly understand viewpager, Download the example and see as well

Say You have Model called Student with `.toBundle` and `.toModel` method like

```
public class Model {    
    public static final String MODEL_ID_KEY = "modelIdKey";
    public static final String MODEL_TITLE_KEY = "modelTitleKey";   

    private int userId;
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public Bundle toBundle(){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(MODEL_ID_KEY, this.getId());
        bundle.putString(MODEL_TITLE_KEY, this.getTitle());;
        return bundle;

    }

    public Model toModel (Bundle bundle){

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setId(bundle.getInt(MODEL_ID_KEY));
        model.setTitle(bundle.getString(MODEL_TITLE_KEY));
        return model;

    }
}
```

Simply you have a XML containing `ViewPager`

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

You have `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` which extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(modelList.get(position).toBundle());
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

}
```

Where `ItemFragment` looks like this

```
 public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {
    Model model;

    TextView tvId;
    TextView tvTitle;



    public ItemFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle !=null) {
            model = new Model();
            this.model = model.toModel(bundle);
        }



    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fragment,container,false);

        tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
        tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);


        if(this.model !=null) {
            tvId.setText(String.valueOf(model.getId()));
            tvTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Then just set the `adapter` in `MainActivity`

```
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    myPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```